# I am getting this Error: Field '_controller' should be initialized because its type 'AnimationController' doesn't allow null. How do I instantiate?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgZEb.png)

Am I missing something? Is there another way to instantiate the controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class AnimatedLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _AnimatedLogginPageState();
  }
}

class _AnimatedLogginPageState extends State<AnimatedLoginPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller; // <- ERROR HERE
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dart is null safe**
So you should define your controller like:

```
late AnimationController _controller;
or 
AnimationController? _controller;
```

**References**:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html